# What I am doing wrong in my hsqldb script file?

Tags: mule, hsqldb

I am trying to use hsqldb for unit testing of mule flow which involves db operation. I have never used hsqldb before. here is the url which i use for db connection however db connection is successful

db.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb:file:test;sql.syntax_pgs=true;
db.driver=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver

```
SET DATABASE UNIQUE NAME HSQLDB57B7E1353C
SET DATABASE GC 0
SET DATABASE DEFAULT RESULT MEMORY ROWS 0
SET DATABASE EVENT LOG LEVEL 0
SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL LOCKS
SET DATABASE DEFAULT ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
SET DATABASE TRANSACTION ROLLBACK ON CONFLICT TRUE
SET DATABASE TEXT TABLE DEFAULTS ''
SET DATABASE SQL NAMES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL REFERENCES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL SIZE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TYPES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL TDC DELETE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TDC UPDATE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TRANSLATE TTI TYPES TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TRANSLATE TTI TYPES TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL CONCAT NULLS TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL UNIQUE NULLS TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL CONVERT TRUNCATE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL AVG SCALE 0
SET DATABASE SQL DOUBLE NAN TRUE
SET FILES WRITE DELAY 500 MILLIS
SET FILES BACKUP INCREMENT TRUE
SET FILES CACHE SIZE 10000
SET FILES CACHE ROWS 50000
SET FILES SCALE 32
SET FILES LOB SCALE 32
SET FILES DEFRAG 0
SET FILES NIO TRUE
SET FILES NIO SIZE 256
SET FILES LOG TRUE
SET FILES LOG SIZE 50
CREATE USER SA PASSWORD DIGEST 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'
ALTER USER SA SET LOCAL TRUE
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA
ALTER SEQUENCE SYSTEM_LOBS.LOB_ID RESTART WITH 1
SET DATABASE DEFAULT INITIAL SCHEMA PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SQL_IDENTIFIER TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.YES_OR_NO TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TIME_STAMP TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CARDINAL_NUMBER TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHARACTER_DATA TO PUBLIC
GRANT DBA TO SA

CREATE DATABASE testdb;

CREATE SEQUENCE batch_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE public."csv_3.4.3" 
(
  seq_id serial NOT NULL,
  batch_id integer NOT NULL,
  "institution name" character varying(2000),
  "institution customer number" character varying(2000),
  "first name" character varying(2000),
  "last name" character varying(2000),
  email character varying(2000),
  marketable character varying(2000),
  status character varying(2000),
  source character varying(100)
)
```

but when I run my flow getting this following error:

Message : user lacks privilege or object not found: csv_3.4.3

Kindly help me.

Comment: You don't need a script like that. HSQLDB itself will perform the tasks. All you need to do is execute your CREATE SEQUENCE and CREATE TABLE statements after connecting.

Comment: Thank you for replying fredt. I had tried only with writing sequence and table structure, but no luck. Same error when I run unit test which refers to the actual flow.  Do I need to do any configuration setting?. I have just added jar file to classpath and have one test.script file. Do I need anything else?.

Comment: Forget about the .script file and execute SQL statements to create the table and the sequence.